# Selecting by element ID + element class yields same element twice

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

Why is jQuery returning same element twice here?

Checked the HTML numerous times, there's only one `<div>` with `id="3"` and `class="password_field_real"`.

This is the result for getting all elements with `class="password_field_real"`:

```
> $(".password_field_real")

[
    <div class="password_field_real" id="2" style="display: none;"></div>, 
    <div class="password_field_real" id="3" style="display: none;"></div>,
    <div class="password_field_real" id="7" style="display: none;"></div>,
]
```

However, when I try to get `class="password_field_real"` and `id="3"`, I get a list of two divs, which are the same!

```
> $("#3.password_field_real")

[
    <div class="password_field_real" id="3" style="display: none;"></div>,  
    <div class="password_field_real" id="3" style="display: none;"></div>
]
```

This is not the case with other two divs:

```
> $("#7.password_field_real")

[
    <div class="password_field_real" id="7" style="display: none;"></div>
]
```

Why could this happen?

*** UPDATE ***

[Reproduced](http://jsfiddle.net/SdfCC/) this in jsFiddle

*** UPDATE #2 ***

If non-numeric ID's are used, everything [works just fine](http://jsfiddle.net/Fmfjn/).

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? Can you come up with a jsFiddle or similar which demonstrates this problem? I can't reproduce this with jQuery 1.9.1 (http://jsfiddle.net/B7S2f/).

Comment: you do know numeric IDs are only legal in HTML5 ?

Comment: I think there should not any problem, if you are facing the problem then first clear the `cache and cookies` then check it again.

Comment: @DreamEater: I rolled back your edit as you destroyed the console formatting in the post.

Comment: @Alnitak: That doesn't matter.

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem...

Comment: Thank you for the answers! The problematic code also involves jQuery UI Accordions, the `div` elements are located inside them. I'll try to publish HTML code later this day.

Comment: Done: http://jsfiddle.net/SdfCC/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Fmfjn/ — non-numeric ID's are fine though. Strange.

Comment: id are for unique element, here you use 8 elements with the id "3" ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, an `id` must be unique on a page. That is the idea behind it.

Your problem is that you use an invalid ID selector (according to [HTML4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html)):

> 1. ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>      followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>      underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

In other doctypes there are different restrictions, but you always need at least one letter. Since you only use a number, it is invalid. That might be the explanation when you use non-numeric ID's everythings fine. Still it's a bit weird behaviour of jQuery.

Prepend your ID's with at least one letter `[A-Za-z]`, or even better, make it descriptive.

Answer (score 7):

NEVER use multiple time the same id, id MUST be UNIQUE

```
alert( $("#3").length ); // will just return 1 not 8
```

this really dumb code just select your good one, but never use that, will cause end of world

```
alert( $("#3").find("#3").filter(".password_field_real").attr("class") );
```

if you need current id for each sub "div" and "a", try data- with why not a code like that

```
$(".password_entry").each(function(){
    var $t = $(this);
    var currentId = $t.attr("id");
    $t.find("div,a").data("id",currentId);
});
```

now you can extract current id from all sub "div" and "a" with .data("id")

by exemple :

```
$(".password_field_mask").click(function(){ alert( $(this).data("id") ); });
```